# Ruby Net::HTTP not sending TCP Keep-Alive packets, resulting in "Errno::ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer" exceptions

Tags: ruby, ssl, networking, tcp

I'm interacting with an API that accepts POST requests over HTTPS and responds with XML. The data take a long time for the remote server to generate, which means that my local client waits for several minutes between sending its POST request and receiving a response. Sometimes the response comes back as expected, but other times Ruby (2.3.1p112) raises the following exception after a long pause:

```
Exception occurred: Errno::ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer

/usr/share/ruby/openssl/buffering.rb:178:in `sysread_nonblock'
/usr/share/ruby/openssl/buffering.rb:178:in `read_nonblock'
/usr/share/ruby/net/protocol.rb:154:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/share/ruby/net/protocol.rb:136:in `readuntil'
/usr/share/ruby/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:1437:in `block in transport_request'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:1434:in `transport_request'
/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
```

Out of curiosity, I tried making the same requests using cURL, and found that I got a response back every single time, never encountering a connection reset initiated by the remote host. The cURL and Ruby requests were being run on the same machine, so I figured it wasn't a low-level system or networking issue. Trying to find some difference, I ran Wireshark and looked at the packets being sent back and forth during the requests.

First with Ruby:

```
1302978 3988.123708  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  SSL 286 Client Hello
1302981 3988.189299  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 463 Server Hello, Certificate
1302982 3988.189388  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 55265 → 443 [ACK] Seq=233 Ack=1361 Win=65535 Len=0
1302983 3988.189389  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 55265 → 443 [ACK] Seq=233 Ack=2721 Win=65535 Len=0
1302984 3988.189389  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 55265 → 443 [ACK] Seq=233 Ack=3130 Win=65535 Len=0
1302985 3988.194978  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 396 Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
1302986 3988.195047  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 55265 → 443 [ACK] Seq=233 Ack=3472 Win=65535 Len=0
1302987 3988.195812  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TLSv1.2 180 Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
1302988 3988.257643  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 55265 [ACK] Seq=3472 Ack=359 Win=35098 Len=0
1302989 3988.272131  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 105 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
1302990 3988.272200  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 55265 → 443 [ACK] Seq=359 Ack=3523 Win=65535 Len=0
1302994 3988.339450  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 55265 [ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=945 Win=34512 Len=0
1302995 3988.339455  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 55265 [ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=1206 Win=34251 Len=0
1406186 4376.828078  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 54 443 → 55265 [RST, ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=1206 Win=9300 Len=0
```

Then with cURL:

```
51468 268.062527  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  SSL 292 Client Hello
51472 268.125416  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 463 Server Hello, Certificate
51473 268.125530  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=239 Ack=1361 Win=65535 Len=0
51474 268.125531  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=239 Ack=2721 Win=65535 Len=0
51475 268.125531  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=239 Ack=3130 Win=65535 Len=0
51476 268.132509  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 396 Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
51477 268.132604  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=239 Ack=3472 Win=65535 Len=0
51479 268.158620  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TLSv1.2 129 Client Key Exchange
51481 268.220146  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 53819 [ACK] Seq=3472 Ack=314 Win=35137 Len=0
51482 268.220216  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TLSv1.2 105 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
51483 268.281636  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 53819 [ACK] Seq=3472 Ack=365 Win=35086 Len=0
51484 268.281642  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TLSv1.2 105 Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
51485 268.281718  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=365 Ack=3523 Win=65535 Len=0
51487 268.344020  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 443 → 53819 [ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=770 Win=34681 Len=0
62427 328.950531  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 [TCP Keep-Alive] 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=769 Ack=3523 Win=65535 Len=0
62435 329.012004  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 [TCP Window Update] 443 → 53819 [ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=770 Win=65535 Len=0
72644 389.584563  [local-ip] → [remote-ip]  TCP 54 [TCP Keep-Alive] 53819 → 443 [ACK] Seq=769 Ack=3523 Win=65535 Len=0
72647 389.647037  [remote-ip] → [local-ip]  TCP 60 [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 443 → 53819 [ACK] Seq=3523 Ack=770 Win=65535 Len=0
```

The pertinent difference I found is that cURL is sending a TCP Keep-Alive packet every minute while it waits for a response, letting the server know that it is still active and wishes to keep its connection open. Ruby Net::HTTP is not sending these packets and eventually gets a TCP RST (reset) from the remote host, which triggers the Errno::ECONNRESET exception.

So my question is: is there some way to configure Net::HTTP to send those TCP Keep-Alive packets and keep my connection open? Thanks!

---

**Edit**: I was able to work around this by switching to Typhoeus (which wraps cURL) and passing the option `tcp_keepalive: true` to my requests, which is the flag that [tells cURL to send keepalive probes](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.html).

I'll leave this question open in case someone has insight on whether it's possible to get this same behavior from Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify keep alive in the header of the request, this isn't specific to nethttp though! https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html

Comment: I tried setting that header, but the remote host still eventually sent a RST packet and it did not prompt Net::HTTP to start sending Keep-Alive probes. AFAICT, that header specifies the expectations of the host setting it about how the *other* host needs to behave to keep the connection active.